# Make WP7 Panorama Item Title Smaller or Wrap?

Tags: windows-phone-7

My text is getting cutoff in my Panorama View, I am wondering is there away to wrap the text or make it smaller so it won't get cutoff?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the [TitleTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.titletemplate%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?

```
<phone:Panorama Title="my application">
    <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="50" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
</phone:Panorama>
```